# Display keywords from DB as Checkbox Options

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've created a database using mysqli and I have keywords stored in a table called "Keywords". I need to use the keywords stored in this table to display as options on a form in the form of checkboxes.

So, if the keyword has not been added to the db, then the checkbox on the form will not display for users to choose from. What's the best way to achieve this? My sql knowledge is basic but I can have an idea on how the query might look. Just not sure about how to display them as checkboxes.

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE!
I was able to get my array to display with checkboxes: Here is what I did:

```
<?php
include 'db.php'; 

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM addKeywordTable ORDER BY Keyword_Name ASC");

print <<<HERE
HERE;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$key = $row['Keyword_Name'];
$id = $row["keyID"];

print <<<HERE
<input type="checkbox" id="$key">$key<br />
   HERE;
}
?>
```

NOW MY QUESTION IS: How do I pass the checked value off to my new table (profileTable) a completely separate table containing the form results?

MY FORM CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS (Fri 8/9/13):

```
   <div id="form1profile">
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addProfile" id="addProfile" >
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Add/Create a Media Source Profile</legend>
    <br>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
   <th ><label>First Name</label></th>
    <td><input name="FName" type="text" id="FName" size="40"></td>
     </tr>
 <tr>
  <th >Middle Name</th>
  <td><input name="MName" type="text" id="MName" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th ><label>Last<br>
    Name</label></th>
  <td><input name="LName" type="text" id="LName" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Prefix</label></th>
  <td><input name="Prefix" type="text" id="Prefix" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Title
  </label></th>
  <td><input name="Title" type="text" id="Title" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Dept</label></th>
  <td><input name="Dept" type="text" id="Dept" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Phone</label></th>
  <td><input name="PH1" type="text" id="PH1" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Other Phone</label></th>
  <td><input name="PH2" type="text" id="PH2" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label>Email</label></th>
  <td><input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label for="ProfileImg">Photo</label></th>
  <td><input name="ProfileImg" type="file" multiple id="ProfileImg" form="addProfile">
   </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign="top"><label class="biotextTitle">Bio/Info</label></th>
     <td><textarea name="bioLinks" cols="55" rows="25" id="bioLinks" placeholder="Paste Bio/Links here..."></textarea></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><label class="Keywords">Keyword</label></th>
     <td>
    <?php include 'db.php'; 

         $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM addKeywordTable ORDER BY Keyword_Name ASC");

         foreach ($_POST['keyword'] as $keyword) {
               if ($keyword) {
            // $keyword is a selected keyword
          }
        } 

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
          {
         $key = $row['Keyword_Name'];
         $id = $row["keyID"];


         print <<<HERE
          <input type="checkbox" name="keyword[$key]" id="$key">$key<br />
         HERE;
          }
       ?> 
         </td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
     <th><label class="tags">Tags</label></th>
       <td><input name="Tags" type="text" id="Tags" size="40"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th><input name="SaveBtn" type="submit" id="SaveBtn" formaction="insertProfile.php" formmethod="POST" value="Save"></th>
        <td></td>
          </tr>
            </table>
         <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: have you written some basic code on how to create an HTML form using PHP ?

Comment: Looks like i may have answered my own question: I used <input type="checkbox" id="$key">$key<br/> which gave me my array... I've added it(code) to my question above. How would I pass this option off to my new table when the checkbox is checked???

Comment: you need to write additional logic to process the form. Do you have that with you ? Also I am not sure what does this do: print <<<HERE
HERE;  or if its needed at all.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yes... i just added it to my post. It's the code to my entire form which processes the checkboxes array. Please have a look and tell me where i'm going wrong at.

Comment: if you are looking for specific issues with your code then I suggest that you post this on the code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ It is better suited there.

Comment: More less looking for ideas on how to pass my id to my db. I posted the code as a request from u in the 3rd comment.dont need a code review.

Comment: have you created fields in your database where you will be storing the keywords? The logic is simple: you create a form where the user checks the keywords using checkboxes, then you process that form using $_POST array and after validating the values, you write them into the database.See if this link helps: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/insert-value-from-checkbox-in-database-mysql-in-php/

Comment: My database is created YES. But i am storing the values of my Keyword column in the keyword field of the form. I need to then send those keywords to a seperate column in the userProfile table that will classify the user with the selected keywords. Hope this helps... still stuck at this point :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `name` to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword[$key]" value="1">$key<br />
```

Doing so, when the page is submit you just need to iterate through the selected keywords:

```
foreach ($_POST['keyword'] as $keyword) {
    if ($keyword) {
        // $keyword is a selected keyword
    }
}
```

After that you can get all the selected keywords, then you shall just insert them into your table.

Comment: so the foreach ($_POST['keyword'] as $keyword) would go into my insertPage.php or on my keyword form??! but how would i edit my values '$_POST[keywordName]"???

Comment: It may go on the page your form is redirecting to. I'm not quite sure about what you want to do after you have the selected keywords...

Comment: I am attempting to store the keyword in the db... but the catch is, is the keyword is being populated by another table... I need to store the selected keyword in a separate table.

Comment: I think this answer is as close as it gets to your original question. The only other thing that I can think of is that you need to create fields in your database to which you will insert the values of the selected keywords in this if loop: if ($keyword){ // insert into database }

Comment: I have a seperate table where keywords are created and stored... those keywords then appear on my form (above) which will allow users of the above form to store selected keywords that have been checked. How would I pass my checkbox $keyword in the above form code to my profileTable keyword column?

Answer (score 0):

change this --

```
print <<<HERE
<input type="checkbox" id="$key">$key<br />
   HERE;
```

to this

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='tag_$id'>$key<br />";
```

reason for doing this is so you eliminate all character combinations by just using numeric only. character combo for EX. id="Ava/Flight", id="Ava Flight"